# Understanding the Definition of Indefinite Integral Using Riemann Sums

Tags: calculus, limits, indefinite-integrals, riemann-sum

The definite integral of a function $f$ from $x=a$ to $x=b$ and $\Delta x = (b-a)/n$ is defined by the limit of a Riemann Sum:

$$
\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(a+i\cdot\Delta x) \cdot \Delta x
$$

I am curious about the definition of the indefinite integral expressed through the limit of a Riemann Sum. Could you also clarify the concepts of upper and lower bounds in this context?

$$
\int_{}^{} f(x) dx = \text{?}
$$

Comment: The indefinite integral is not defined in terms of a Riemann sum. The definite integral is a number while the indefinite integral is a family of functions.

Comment: @jgd1729 thanks a lot. But how I am writing that. Is there no "real definition". What does the indefinite integral really means? THX and BR

Comment: The indefinite integral is defined as follows: if $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=f'(x)$, then $\int f'(x) dx = f(x) +C$ for any real number $C$. In other words, the indefinite integral is just the collection of all antiderivatives of the integrand. Definite and indefinite integrals are really two completely different concepts that happen to be related by the fundamental theorem of calculus.